# Eclipse "organize imports" changes the order of existing imports

Tags: eclipse, code-generation

Using Eclipse Juno (3.8/4.2), when I press ⇧⌘O (shift+ctrl+o), it organizes imports according to the Organize Imports preferences; fine.
Now imagine I'm working on some source code I checked out from SVN, and I add some code depending on new classes, I'd like Eclipse to add the new imports, WITHOUT messing with the existing order of imports (for commit's clarity sake)

for example :

```
package toto;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.AsyncWebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
```

will be organized in :

```
package toto;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.AsyncWebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
```

according to my preferences.

I want to avoid that, I just want to add the imports necessary for the new code I added (I don't want to organize already existing imports), is there something else than Organize Imports to do that ? (I know I can click on the error hint on the left of my new code needing a new import to add it, but I'd like a keyboard shortcut instead)
thanks for your help!

Comment: Once it's organized, it stays organized and in that order.  Just check it in that way.

Comment: not if some team members organize it in a  different way; shift+ctrl+o will re organize everything according to the current organize import preferences

Comment: It's settable as a project-specific preference, but if there will never be agreement, I would simply suggest that no one ever change them.  Otherwise, what Bananeweizen suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> on an error marker to fix a missing import, repeat by jumping to the next error with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>. There is no other possibility to fix all imports in one go than organizing them (which you don't want).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a single keyboard shortcut, but you can do what you describe in a series of steps using the keyboard only:

- Press `Ctrl+.` to go to the next error in the code
- Press `Ctrl+1` to display the quick fixes
- Press Enter to add the import.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I would prefer to have something that would deal with all import related errors, like shift+ctrl+o does...